# Did Socrates say that a higher thing than commerce is war?

Tags: socrates, philosophy-of-war

[Hillsdale College](https://www.Hillsdale.edu) offers a [free course online on math and logic](https://online.hillsdale.edu/courses/mathematics-and-logic-from-euclid-to-modern-geometry). It's taught by two math professors, but the first lecture is an introduction to the pair of subjects by the president of the college,  Larry Arnn.

In that first lecture, at *t* = 10:37 .. 11:27, Arnn says, "In Plato's *Republic* and ... *Statesman*, ... Socrates talks about such a hierarchy. ... And this hierarchy is, first of all, mathematics is useful if you have to go buy your groceries. ... then he goes on, ... **A higher thing than commerce is war** ... because war is necessary to the preservation of the city."

The notion that war is something good is startling to me.

I tried Googling "A higher thing than commerce is war," but it appears to be a paraphrase and nothing like that came up.

Did Socrates say words with that meaning? Arnn says it was in both the *Republic* and *Statesman*. Can I get an exact reference, so I can read where he said that in context?

Comment: See [Plato: The Government of Philosopher Rulers](https://iep.utm.edu/platopol/#H5):  The happiness of the whole city is not for Plato the happiness of an abstract unity called the polis, or the happiness of the greatest number, but rather the happiness of all citizens derived from a peaceful, harmonious, and cooperative union of different social classes. The philosopher-rulers enjoy respect and contemplative leisure, but not wealth or honors;

Comment: the guardian class, the second class in the city, military honors, but not leisure or wealth; and the producer class, family life, wealth, and freedom of enterprise, but not honors or rule. Then, the producers supply the city with goods; the guardians, defend it; and the philosophers, attuned to virtue and illuminated by goodness, rule it impartially for the common benefit of all citizens. The three different social classes engage in mutually beneficial enterprise, by which the interests of all are best served. See [*Republic*, **Bk.VII**](https://classics.mit.edu/Plato/republic.8.vii.html)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - Does any of that have anything to do with war, and in particular, with war being a good thing?